# Using an if function to start a song/video Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

Bear with me. I'm somewhat new to this and I'm slowly but surely learning more and more. Right now I'm creating a simple and easy game based around golf. I want a certain song to start playing if the amount of points scored matches the amount of players. Then, the tally (not score) resets, so that it can occur again in the same game. So far, I've been able to create code that is able to alert the user when this occurs and reset the tally (again not the score). I also have code that plays the song every time the submit button is clicked and it works perfectly. However, when I try to use that music player function inside of the `if` statement that determines when to play the song and alert the user and reset the tally etc., the music does not play at all. Any help is greatly appreciated!

here's the code for the player:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#play-video').on('click', function(ev) {
        $("#video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
        ev.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

here's the javascript code for the if function that I want it to perform inside of

```
function Wow(){
    var amountOfPlayers= document.getElementById("userInput").innerHTML;
    if (tallyMark==amountOfPlayers){
        alert("You Did It!");
        tallyMark=0;
    }
    document.getElementById("tallies").innerHTML = tallyMark;
}
```

Here's the HTML code for the submit button (which runs many functions)

```
    <input id="play-video" href="#" type="submit" onClick="onClick(); scoreTally(); tally(); Wow();" value="Submit"></input>
```

And here's the HTML code for the video it's getting the song from:

```
   <iframe id="video" width="0" height="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QZXc39hT8t4?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" ></iframe>
```

Comment: Where is the code in the `if` statement that's supposed to play the song?

Comment: The first snippet assigns a click handler to the button. Clicking the button will run the video. If you want to do that inside the `Wow` function instead, you need to remove the entire `$(document).ready()` part and instead simply call `$("#video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";` in `Wow`.

Comment: If you have a function that plays the song, you should be able to call that function from the `if` statement.

Comment: It's not there. The code that plays the song is the first code I inputted on this question, at the top. I tried nesting that in the if statement but it doesn't work. My goal is to play the song as soon as the alert says "You Did It!".

Answer (score 0):

Perform the same action from your function:

```
function Wow(){
    var amountOfPlayers= document.getElementById("userInput").innerHTML;
    if (tallyMark==amountOfPlayers){
        $("#video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
        alert("You Did It!");
        tallyMark=0;
    }
    document.getElementById("tallies").innerHTML = tallyMark;
}
```

Comment: Barmar, I tried that and It unfortunately did not work. I tried

        $("#video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";

and it worked, however it only starts playing once the OK button on the alert is clicked.

Comment: That's still a step forward for me, thanks guys!! Next step is finding out how to stop the song from continuously playing. And also start it at a different point in the song

Comment: Alerts block the browser UI.

Comment: ahhhh makes sense. Do you think console.log would be more appropriate? Eventually I'll probably add graphics instead of console.log or an alert but I'm just learning the basics for now

Comment: Best would be to display the message in the web page.

Comment: How can I do that at the precise time?

Comment: Replace `alert("You did it!")` with `$("#message").text("You did it!")` where `message` is the ID of the field where you display the message.

Comment: Works like a charm!! It's still a bit delayed on the start of the song though. How can I make the message disappear on the next click (like how the tally restarts back to 0)?